# What is the angular equivalent of hasClass?

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying to select elements with a specific class name, then remove and add elements based on that class

Comment: Perhaps you're not entirely clear on how angular works? Generally you don't need to select elements, because you can generate them yourself with an `ngFor` loop.

Comment: This does not look like Angular source code.

Comment: It appears as though you're using `d3` to do... something. I would suggest using Angular for DOM manipulation (by binding to a separate model) rather than d3.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use d3 in angular, and create a button that changes glyph icons when clicked

Comment: You don't need d3 for that. You can do that in HTML and Angular without d3.

Answer (score 3):

User ViewChild to get the element ref then after that Implement `ngDoCheck()` to run the check whether the class was added when change detection runs:

```
export class ClassName implements DoCheck {
      @ViewChild('elementID') elementID:ElementRef;

      ngDoCheck() {
         if(elementID.nativeElement.classList.contains('class-name')) {
            //TODO something
         }
      } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if (element.classList.contains('your-class-name')) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

You can use plain JavaScript.

And can remove:

```
element.classList.remove('your-class-name'))
```

Comment: I am getting an error, Property 'classList' does not exist on type 'Selection<BaseType, unknown, any, unknown>'. My element variable does not recognize classList.

Comment: Add code on your question so we understand how you reference your DOM.

Comment: Added to clarify